# java swing - paint jcomponent

Tags: java, swing, jcomponent

i am try to make chorded keyboard simulation.
I cannot resolve why KeyboardButtons in Keyboard are not painting. I have more KeyboardButtons in Keyboard. Mouse is listened properly, but polygons are not painted.

When i call paint to each KeyboardButton in the Keyboard's paintComponent(), polygons are painted, but not changing color on mousePressed.

**Keyboard.java**

```
package keyboard;


import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Keyboard extends JPanel implements MouseListener{

    Point[] leftFingers;
    Point leftCenter = new Point(300, 600);
    KeyboardButton[] buttons;

    public Keyboard(Point left1, Point left2, Point left3, Point left4, Point left5) {
    leftFingers = new Point[5];
    leftFingers[0] = left1;
    leftFingers[1] = left2;
    leftFingers[2] = left3;
    leftFingers[3] = left4;
    leftFingers[4] = left5;
    buttons = registerKeys();
    addMouseListener(this);
    }

    public KeyboardButton[] registerKeys() {
    Polygon[] polygons = generateKeyPolygons(calculateBordersOfKeys(leftFingers));
    KeyboardButton[] buttons = new KeyboardButton[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < polygons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i] = new KeyboardButton(polygons[i]);

    }
    return buttons;
    }

    private Point[] calculateBordersOfKeys(Point[] fingers) {
    Point[] centers = calculateCentersBetweenEachTwoFingers(fingers);
    Point[] result = new Point[6];

    result[0] = calculateCentralSymmetry(centers[0], fingers[0]);
    System.arraycopy(centers, 0, result, 1, centers.length);
    result[5] = calculateCentralSymmetry(centers[3], fingers[4]);
    return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.drawOval(leftCenter.x - 25, leftCenter.y - 25, 50, 50);

    for (int i = 0; i < leftFingers.length; i++) {
        g.drawOval(leftFingers[i].x, leftFingers[i].y, 10, 10);

    }
    }


    private Polygon[] generateKeyPolygons(Point[] borders) {
    Polygon[] polygons = new Polygon[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < borders.length - 1; i++) {
        Polygon p = new Polygon();
        p.addPoint(leftCenter.x, leftCenter.y);
        p.addPoint(borders[i].x, borders[i].y);
        p.addPoint(borders[i + 1].x, borders[i + 1].y);
        polygons[i] = p;
    }

    return polygons;
    }

    private Point[] calculateCentersBetweenEachTwoFingers(Point[] fingers) {
    Point[] centers = new Point[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < fingers.length - 1; i++) {
        centers[i] = new Point(((fingers[i].x + fingers[i + 1].x) / 2), ((fingers[i].y + fingers[i + 1].y) / 2));
    }
    return centers;
    }

    private Point calculateCentralSymmetry(Point toReflected, Point center) {
    Point reflection = new Point();

    if (toReflected.x > center.x) {
        reflection.x = center.x - Math.abs(center.x - toReflected.x);
    } else {
        reflection.x = center.x + Math.abs(center.x - toReflected.x);
    }

    if (toReflected.y > center.y) {
        reflection.y = center.y - Math.abs(center.y - toReflected.y);
    } else {
        reflection.y = center.y + Math.abs(center.y - toReflected.y);
    }

    return reflection;
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    for (KeyboardButton button : buttons) {
        button.checkMousePosition(e);
    }
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    for (KeyboardButton button : buttons) {
        button.checkMousePosition(e);
    }   
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

    }


}
```

**KeyboardButton.java**

```
package keyboard;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class KeyboardButton extends JComponent {

    Polygon polygon;
    boolean isActive;
    final Color ACTIVE_COLOR = Color.red;
    final Color INACTIVE_COLOR = Color.blue;

    public KeyboardButton(Polygon p) {
    polygon = p;
    }

    public void checkMousePosition(MouseEvent e) {
    if (polygon.contains(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
        setState(true);
    }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(isActive ? ACTIVE_COLOR : INACTIVE_COLOR);
    g.drawPolygon(polygon);
    }

    void setState(boolean state) {
    isActive = state;
    System.out.println(this.hashCode());
    repaint();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the `KeyboardButton` components are never added to the `Keyboard`. So, when they call `repaint()`, it has no effect because they are not part of the view hierarchy.

Comment: And how can I add it? I have tried to call add(KeyboardButton a) in Keyboard contructor (or other method) without any effect ...

Comment: If you need the buttons to be components, you have to add them to the Keyboard and also set their bounds somehow (with a layout manager or absolute positioning) so that they will draw at the proper place. But looking at your code, it seems like it would be simpler to just have the buttons not be components, just plain Java objects that can draw into the `Keyboard` component and that repaint it when they are changed.